# Why sqlite .dump encrypted data to x'2384934..' rather than raw data?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

SQLite Table A has a column `secure_name varchar(128)` that store encrypted data, such as `gAAAAAby5666.......`.
Why did the data change to X'67837483473843....' which length exceeds 128, when i issued command `.dump` to export data to file?

Comment: That's a blob literal, so whatever is stored in that column is stored as a blob, not a string. As for `varchar(128)`... Well... Read https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: That is hexadecimal encoding of binary data.

Answer (score 1):

Because the [.dump command](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-dump/) (emphasis mine):

> converts the entire structure and data of an SQLite database into a single **text file**.

The length of the string literal is irrelevant, what counts is the length of the binary data that it encodes.

Comment: It's not a string literal.

Comment: @Shawn I think it is according to [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#hexint): "BLOB literals are string literals containing hexadecimal data and preceded by a single "x" or "X" character. Example: X'53514C697465' "

Comment: Exactly. It's a blob literal, not a string.

Comment: No, blobs and strings are distinct different types. See for yourself: `SELECT X'1234', typeof(X'1234'), '1234', typeof('1234');`

Comment: @Shawn I'm literally (pun unintended) quoting the official documentation: "BLOB literals are string literals". I'm not sure about what `typeof` adds here because it merely returns the datatype of the expression. It's like arguing that 9.95 is not a number because `typeof` returns `REAL`. If you think it's incorrect you can always submit a bug report of a pull request for the documentation team but I have the impression that you're interpreting in terms of datatypes what's actually a SQL syntax description.

Comment: Um, 9.95 *is* a number... just like x'1234' is a blob, and '1234' is a string, and x'xyz' is a syntax error because blob literals can only have an even number of base-16 digits in them... the only reason the documentation compares one to a string literal is because both use quotes as delimiters; the values they represent are very different.

Answer (score 0):

So... if you expect sqlite to act just like, say, postgres or oracle or another RDMS, you're going to get burnt. It has its own little idiosyncrasies, and it's well worth the time pouring over the documentation to learn just how it works. In this case, the description of [datatypes](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) is vital.

Each value stored in a table has its own associated type. A column's type (AKA affinity) is just the *preferred* storage type for values; if something can be losslessly converted to the desired type, it is, otherwise the original type is used. In this case, since you're seeing `X'...'` values, which are blob literals, the column is being used to store blobs of arbitrary bytes, not unicode strings.

The type of `varchar(128)` is, since it has the string `char` in it, treated as a sqlite `TEXT` column affinity. Blobs cannot be converted to text strings, so the blob values in the table are stored unconverted, and displayed as a blob literal by `.dump`. (Plus length constraints like the `(128)` are ignored anyways.)